# GC ISSUES IN JBOSS EAP7.4

Tags: java, performance, jboss, jboss-eap-7

i recently upgraded to JBoss EAP 7.4 and used below JVM Properties

**JVM PROPERTIES:**

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.65-b01) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_65-b17), built on Oct  6 2015 16:39:20 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
Memory: 4k page, physical 33553400k(30038296k free), swap 38534136k(34295240k free)

```
CommandLine flags: -XX:GCLogFileSize=3145728 -XX:InitialHeapSize=6442450944 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=40 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:MaxHeapSize=6442450944 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=536870912 -XX:MetaspaceSize=268435456 -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=32 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:-UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation
```

**Getting Below errors:**

1. 2023-12-28T04:26:39.672+0000: 4.094: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause)
   (young), 0.0532817 secs]

   2023-12-28T11:53:19.470+0000: 26803.912: [Full GC (Allocation
   Failure)  6138M->5367M(6144M), 8.7086865 secs]    [Eden:
   0.0B(306.0M)->0.0B(306.0M) Survivors: 0.0B->0.0B Heap: 6138.0M(6144.0M)->5367.4M(6144.0M)], [Metaspace: 178416K->178292K(1224704K)]  [Times: user=13.34 sys=0.00, real=8.70
   secs]  2023-12-28T11:53:28.173+0000: 26812.621: [GC
   concurrent-mark-abort] 2023-12-28T11:53:30.033+0000: 26814.474: [GC
   pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.0136633 secs]

Could you please suggest any changes required in My JVM properties

Comment: why are you using such an archaic release of Java 8? the number of security and bugs in that version is mind boggling. You should seriously consider upgrading. It may not help with the issue but there must be a lot of G1 fixes in newer Java 8 updates. Also, how were those JVM arguments selected? Did you test them before to ensure they were working correctly? What was the decision process to select each one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tuning JVM 8 G1 argument to avoid Full GC (Allocation Failure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54477197/how-to-tuning-jvm-8-g1-argument-to-avoid-full-gc-allocation-failure)